# Initialization of const with function using extern const

Tags: c++, c, c++11, arduino

Initialization of a const produces different results on different platforms. I get the expected result on the Arduino UNO(AVR) and I get unexpected results on the Arduino Due (Cortex M-3).
This is the essence of my problem:

const_problem.ino:

```
typedef struct{
  int x;
}
my_type_t;

my_type_t init_my_type0(void);
my_type_t init_my_type1(void);
my_type_t init_my_type2(void);

static const my_type_t my_type_0=init_my_type0();
static const my_type_t my_type_1=init_my_type1();
static const my_type_t my_type_2=init_my_type2();

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  Serial.print("my_type_0.x: ");
  Serial.println(my_type_0.x);//5
  Serial.print("my_type_1.x: ");
  Serial.println(my_type_1.x);//ARDUINO DUE (CORTEX M-3): 0, Arduino UNO (AVR): 5 
  Serial.print("my_type_2.x: ");
  Serial.println(my_type_2.x);//5

  const my_type_t my_type_3=init_my_type1();
  Serial.print("my_type_3.x: ");
  Serial.println(my_type_3.x);//5
}

void loop() {}
```

const.c:

```
const int some_constant = 5;
```

utils.cpp:

```
extern "C"{
extern const int some_constant;
}

static const int  some_constant_copy =  some_constant;
static const int *some_constant_p    = &some_constant;

typedef struct{
  int x;
}
my_type_t;

my_type_t init_my_type0(void){
    return (my_type_t){some_constant};
}

my_type_t init_my_type1(void){
    return (my_type_t){some_constant_copy};
}

my_type_t init_my_type2(void){
    return (my_type_t){*some_constant_p};
}
```

I expect 5 with function init_my_type1, but I get the value 0 (only on one platform and only for filescope constant). Why is that?

Comment: Note: `static const timer_divider_settings_t BIT_PERIOD_S = timer_divider_settings_calc(0,LN_BIT_PERIOD_S);` is not "initialize a constant struct with using a function at _compile time_" in C.  Perhaps a C extension? "I expect it to be the same regardless of the target platform." is not certian with C.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to add extern "C" in the header file or, if not possible, around the include:

```
extern "C" {
#include "myheaderfile.h"
}
```

Other than that, you could try to run just the preprocessor and see the output; perhaps it is not what you expected. If you are using gcc,

```
g++ -I include_path -E abstract.cpp
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Extern "C" didn't help. I couldn't find a way to view the preprocessor output in arduino(I have no choice for this platform). I have found a work around myself.